# Añadir validacion de clave primaria en una type collection en sonata admin (en el formulario)

Tags: php, mysql, validación, symfony3, doctrine2

He configurado el backend de un proyecto en Symfony 3 con el bundle sonata admin. Tengo una relacion one to many y en la clase admin de la entidad A un sonata type collection para meter en la entidad A algunos objetos de la entidad B. El problema es que en la entidad B hay una clave primaria multiple, y cuando actualizo el formulario (entidad A) con una ID repetida de la entidad B me da un maravilloso UniqueConstraintViolationException y no se como validarlo antes en el formulario y mostrar el error ahí.

Os muestro el código, así es mas fácil de entender:

Esta es la entidad A (Feed):

```
class Feed
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /** 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FeedSeason", mappedBy="idFeed", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $seasons;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->seasons = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set seasons
     *
     * @param string $seasons
     *
     * @return Feed
     */
     public function setSeasons($seasons)
     {
        $this->seasons = $seasons;

        return $this;
     }

    /**
     * Add season
     *
     * @param \KoiBundle\Entity\FeedSeason $season
     *
     * @return Feed
     */
     public function addSeason(FeedSeason $season)
     {
         $season->setIdFeed($this);
         $this->seasons[] = $season;
         return $this;
     }

    /**
     * Remove season
     *
     * @param \KoiBundle\Entity\FeedSeason $season
     */
    public function removeSeason(\KoiBundle\Entity\FeedSeason $season)
    {
       $this->seasons->removeElement($season);
    }

    /**
     * Get seasons
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
     public function getSeasons()
     {
        return $this->seasons;
     }
```

/**

Entidad B (FeedSeason)

```
/**
 * FeedSeason
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="feed_seasons")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="KoiBundle\Repository\FeedSeasonRepository")
 */
class FeedSeason
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Feed", inversedBy="seasons", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_feed", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     *
     */

    private $idFeed;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Season", inversedBy="feed", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_season", referencedColumnName="id_season", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $idSeason;

    /**
     * Set idFeed
     *
     * @param integer $idFeed
     *
     * @return FeedSeason
     */
    public function setIdFeed($idFeed)
    {
        $this->idFeed = $idFeed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idFeed
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIdFeed()
    {
        return $this->idFeed;
    }

    /**
     * Set idSeason
     *
     * @param integer $idSeason
     *
     * @return FeedSeason
     */
    public function setIdSeason($idSeason)
    {
        $this->idSeason = $idSeason;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idSeason
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getIdSeason()
    {
        return $this->idSeason;
    }
}
```

Entidad Season (creo que no es importante en el problema):

```
/**
 * Season
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="seasons")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="KoiBundle\Repository\SeasonRepository")
 */
class Season
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_season", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $idSeason;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name_season", type="string", length=10)
     */
    private $nameSeason;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FeedSeason", mappedBy="idSeason", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $feed;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->idSeason;
    }

    /**
     * Set nameSeason
     *
     * @param string $nameSeason
     *
     * @return Season
     */
    public function setNameSeason($nameSeason)
    {
        $this->nameSeason = $nameSeason;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nameSeason
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNameSeason()
    {
        return $this->nameSeason;
    }

    /**
     * Set id
     *
     * @param integer $id
     *
     * @return Season
     */
    public function setIdSeason($id)
    {
        $this->idSeason = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idSeason
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getIdSeason()
    {
        return $this->idSeason;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return strval($this->getNameSeason());
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->feed = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add feed
     *
     * @param \KoiBundle\Entity\FeedSeason $feed
     *
     * @return Season
     */
    public function addFeed(\KoiBundle\Entity\FeedSeason $feed)
    {
        $this->feed[] = $feed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove feed
     *
     * @param \KoiBundle\Entity\FeedSeason $feed
     */
    public function removeFeed(\KoiBundle\Entity\FeedSeason $feed)
    {
        $this->feed->removeElement($feed);
    }

    /**
     * Get feed
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getFeed()
    {
        return $this->feed;
    }
}
```

Then I have the class Feed Admin with the configureFormFields:

```
/**
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper $formMapper
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->with('General')
            ->add('seasons', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'label' => 'Seasons',
                'by_reference' => false,
                'required' => false,
            ),
                array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                    'sortable' => 'position',
                ))
            ->end();
    }
```

Como puedo validar en el formulario de la clase admin (sonata type collection) y mostrar un mensaje en este formulario si la clave primaria en FeedSeasons ya existe? Lo he intentado con UniqueConstraint y UniqueEntity en ambas entidades pero no funciona.

Screenshoot: [Form in the class FeedAdmin with the collection of seasons and one repeated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTf73.png)
Error:

```
 [3/4] UniqueConstraintViolationException: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO feed_seasons (id_feed, id_season) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [3, 3]:

    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3-3' for key 'PRIMARY'   +
```

2. Como puedo validar que el input en el form collection no esté vacío?

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que lo que buscas es el método **validate** del admin:

```
public function validate (ErrorElement $errorElement, $object)
{
    // aqui puedes buscar en la bbdd, y ver si esta repetido el objeto
    // si encuentras el object en la bbdd, haz:
    $oobb = $this->getModelManager()
           ->getRepository(Entity::class)
           ->findBy(...) ;

    if($oobb != $object)
         // el objeto no existe en la bbdd
         return true;


    // el objeto existe? pues añadimos un error.
    $errorElement->addViolation("Objeto repetido");
}
```

En este metodo puedes poner muchas mas condiciones, es cuestión de tu lógica de negocio.

Comment: Buscaba exactamente eso! Muchas gracias!